# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: wrong name:

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to compile and run my java program from the command line.

```
package phoneticSearchPackage;

public class PhoneticSearch {
```

My folder structure is:

`src\PhoneticSearchPackage\PhoneticSearch.java`
Beside the `src` folder is the `.classpath` and `.project`

I compile it using:

```
javac PhoneticSearchPackage/PhoneticSearch.java
```

Which creates a `PhoneticSearch.class` beside the `PhoneticSearch.java`

When I try to run it using:

```
java PhoneticSearchPackage.PhoneticSearch
```

I get this:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PhoneticSearchPackage
/PhoneticSearch (wrong name: phoneticSearchPackage/PhoneticSearch)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)`

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Check the character case.

Comment: Java is **cAsE SENsitivE**. The first `P` from `PhoneticSearchPackage` should be lowercase.

Comment: @BackSlash God I am stupid. Thank you

Comment: There's a HUGE difference between stupid, and just looking at code too long to see small things like that.

Comment: @csmckelvey I know, looking at it way too long, fresh eyes are brilliant :)

Answer (score 3):

make it `java phoneticSearchPackage.PhoneticSearch`